# Linear operators on vectors are Tensors?

Tags: vectors, tensors

I am going through a book on Mechanics (*Introduction to the mechanics of a continuous medium* by Lawrence Malvern, page 132 last section), and it has the following claim at a few places

> **T** is a second-order tensor because it is a linear vector function associating antecedent vectors $\vec{n}$ the image vectors $\frac{d\vec{u}}{dS}$

1) But **T** has the Cartesian components as $\frac{du_i}{dx_j}$. How does this guarantee linearity. Am I missing something here?

For example $u_1$ could be $x_1^3$, then $\frac{du_1}{dx_1}$ would be $3x_1^2$ (i.e. not linear operation)

2) I thought transformation laws dictate if something can be called a Tensor. Does linearity imply the same? (If so won't any matrix qualify as a Tensor)

Comment: A more precise statement about "linear operators on vectors" is that they can be *represented* by matrices. It would be better to give a specific citation for your "book on Mechanics" (including a page number) if you want help with understanding a passage.  At present the Question lacks enough context to be sure what the book tries to say and where you are having difficulty.

Comment: I think you're thinking about your "example" incorrectly. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a linear operator on functions meaning $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (af+bg)=a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f+b\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g$. This does not mean that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f$ will be a linear function

Comment: By that logic any Matrix would be a Tensor correct? But I have been told otherwise. (Also added the book name, I will try to add more details) @hardmath

Comment: @AdamMartens I think I see what you mean. So, the form of components does not matter as long as it follows *op(af+bg)*=*a* x *op(f)*+*b* x *op(g)*.

Comment: @User10482 That's right. A tensor that takes $n$ vectors (in a vector space $V$) to numbers is just a multilinear map to numbers. i.e. a multilinear map $T:V^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Such is called a $(0,n)$ type tensor. A $(m,n)$-type tensor is a multilinear map $V^*\times \dots \times V^* \times V \times \dots \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ (here there are $m$ copies of $V^*$ and $n$ copies of $V$